# To find total size of Linux Installation

Tags: linux

The total size of linux installation can be found out using the command cat /proc/meminfo.
The output of the command cat /proc/meminfo has been pasted below:

```
**root@ubuntu:~# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        2945180 kB
MemFree:          246192 kB
Buffers:          628264 kB
Cached:          1209428 kB
SwapCached:            8 kB
Active:          1109340 kB
Inactive:        1371376 kB
Active(anon):     367848 kB
Inactive(anon):   525764 kB
Active(file):     741492 kB
Inactive(file):   845612 kB
Unevictable:       35316 kB
Mlocked:           33800 kB
SwapTotal:        262140 kB
SwapFree:         254360 kB
Dirty:               228 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        678272 kB
Mapped:           152292 kB
Shmem:            241028 kB
Slab:             102520 kB
SReclaimable:      70884 kB
SUnreclaim:        31636 kB
KernelStack:        3272 kB
PageTables:        27912 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     1734728 kB
Committed_AS:    3313224 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      553504 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359174859 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       63488 kB
DirectMap2M:     1894400 kB**
```

Is there any other command to find the total size of linux installation.

Comment: That's giving you the information of how much memory is used, not how much the installation is taking up.

Comment: straight after a linux install you could run df -m or df -h and that will show you in megs or gigs how much space is used which gives you an idea of the install size.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your packaging system.  Essentially, you'd want to query the size of all installed packages on your system.

Alternatively, you could use df and du to calculate the used space, subtracting out /tmp and /home.